# Dynamic 2D array in c++ causing problems

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, 2d

So i am making a connect 4 game that can work on any size board for connecting any amount and uses an ai to play against you. Currently, it doesnt display the board properly and I am not convinced the board is being created properly. The other problem is I get a break error when I actually try to place the first coin. (Error message: "First-chance exception at 0x00195832 in Connect[x,n].exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x5A5A5A57." and happens in my add function for the board where i try to set the array's "top" location to a player/ai coin.

Overall, I just dont think im using a 2d dynamic array properly in c++ and was hoping someone could see my errors here

my 'main' cpp

```
// Connect[x,n].cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "time.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "winioctl.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include "AIConnectBoard.h"


using namespace std;





int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char again;
    int tm, tn, conNum;
    char aiturn;

do{

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //random seed based on time
    cout << "Board Width:";
    cin >> tn;
    cout << "Board Height:";
    cin >> tm;
    cout << "Connect?";
    cin >> conNum;
    cout << "AI moves first?(y/n)";
    cin >> aiturn;


    AIConnectBoard *b = new AIConnectBoard();
    b->setBoard(tm, tn);
    b->setFirst(aiturn);


    while (b->checkwin()==0) //keep asking for moves until someone wins
    {
        b->dispBoard();
        if (b->endt == 0)
        {
            int coincol;
            if (b->turn == b->plyr)
            {
                do
                {
                cout << "What column?" << "(1"<< "-" << tn << ")" << '\n';
                cin >> coincol;

                if ((coincol > tn) || (coincol < 1))
                {
                    cout << "That is not an accepted value, please enter a number between 1 and " << tn <<'\n';
                }

                }while ((coincol > tn) || (coincol < 1));
                coincol--;
            }
            if (b->add(coincol, b->plyr) == 0)
            {
                if (b->endt == 0)
                {
                    if (b->add(coincol, b->plyr) == 0)
                    {
                        b->lin = 6 - b->top[coincol]; //place players choice
                        b->checkturn();
                        b->turn = b->ai;

                        if (b->endt == 0)
                        {
                            int t;
                            b->col = b->Think();
                            t = b->add(b->col, b->ai);
                            if (t == 0)
                            {
                                b->lin = 6 - b->top[b->col]; //place ai's choice
                                b->turn = b->plyr;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Play Again? (y/n)";
    cin >> again;
} while (again != 'n');
return 0;
};
```

my aiconnectboard.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AIConnectBoard.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "time.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "winioctl.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//constructor
AIConnectBoard::AIConnectBoard(){
endt = 0;
turn = 1;
}

//destructor
AIConnectBoard::~AIConnectBoard()
{

}

//create board to m x n specifications
void AIConnectBoard::setBoard(const int tn, const int tm)
{
n = tn;
m = tm;
noPlayer = 0;
plyr = 1;
ai = 2;
int** arry = 0;
arry = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //make board 2d && make empty
{
    arry[i] = new int[m];
    arry[i][m] = noPlayer;
}

int** thnk = new int*[m, n];
int* top = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) //set top to bottom of board
{
    top[i] = 0;
}
return;
}

//sets first plyr/turn. Red moves first, then Yellow
void AIConnectBoard::setFirst(char a)
{
if (a == 'y') //ai goes first
    {
        turn=ai;
        aiColor= 'R';
        plyrColor= 'Y';
    }
else //plyr goes first
{
    turn=plyr;
    aiColor= 'Y';
    plyrColor = 'R';
}
}

//output board

*******GETS OUPUT AS 2 ROWS OF 0s AND DOESNT FILL EVERYTHING

void AIConnectBoard::dispBoard()
{
for (int x=1;x<=m;x++) //rows on top of board
{
    cout << x << " ";
}
cout << '\n';
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) //display current state of board
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (arry[i,j] == (int*)1)
        {
            cout << plyrColor << " ";
        }
        if (arry[i,j] == (int*)2)
        {
            cout << aiColor << " ";
        }
        else if (arry[i,j]==(int*)0)
        {
            cout << "O  ";
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
}

//AI starts thinking--set difficulty here
int AIConnectBoard::Think() //levels of recursion
{
int i = (m*n)/7; //will give 6 levels of recursion on 7x6
i = recur;
return check(i);
}

//check for an end to game (win/lose/draw)
void AIConnectBoard::checkturn()
{
int temp;
temp = checkwin();
if (temp == plyr)
{
    cout << "You win!" << '\n';
    endt=1;
}
else if (temp == ai)
{
    cout << "You lose!" << '\n';
    endt=1;
}
else if (temp == 0)
{
    for (t = 0; t < n; t++)
    {
        if (n - top[t] < 0)
        {
            temp = 1;
        }
    }
    if (temp == 0)
    {
        endt = 1;
        return;
    }
}
}

//1st AI check score of move function
int AIConnectBoard::check(int i)
{
int co, score, t, g, j = 0, p;
i--;
if (i == -1)
{
    score = position();
    return score;
}

if (i % 2 == 0)
{
    int max = 0, k;
    int j = 0;
    int co = 0;
    for (t = 0; t < n; t++)
    {
        g = add(t, ai);
        if (g == 0)
        {
            if (checkwin() == ai)
            {
                sub(t);

                if (i == recur - 1)
                {
                    return t;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 9000;
                }
            }
            k = check(i);

            if (co == 0)
            {
                max = k;
                co = 1;
                j = t;
            }

            if (k == max)
            {
                p = rand() % m + 1;
                if (p > 4)
                {
                    j = t;
                }
            }

            if (k > max)
            {
                max = k;
                j = t;
            }
            sub(t);
        }
        score = max;
    }
}
else
{
    int min = 0, k = 0;
    co = 0;
    for (t = 0; t < m; t++)
    {
        g = add(t, plyr);
        if (g == 0)
        {
            if (checkwin() == plyr)
            {
                sub(t);
                return -10000;
            }
            k = check(i);
            if (co == 0)
            {
                min = k; co = 1; j = t;
                if (k < min)
                {
                    min = k;
                    j = t;
                }
            }
            sub(t);
        }
        score = min;
    }
}
if (i == recur - 1)
{
    return j;
}
return score;
}


//add a coin to the specified c column (g for ai vs plyr)
int AIConnectBoard::add(int c, int g)
{
int* coin;
int tcoin = 0;
coin = &tcoin; //initialize coin to something

//set coin to be ai or player
if (g == plyr)
{
    coin = &plyr;
}
if (g == ai)
{
    coin = &ai;
}
//if not at top of board, drop coin and increase top array
if (top[c] < n)
{
    if (g == plyr)
    {
        arry[c][top[c]] = plyr;   *******WHERE I GET THE EXCEPTION ERROR (ASSUMING IM USING A NULL POINTER OR SOMETHING, BUT CANT TELL WHERE)
        top[c]++;
    }
    else if (g == ai)
    {
        arry[c][top[c]] = ai;
        top[c]++;
    }
    return 1;
}
}



//remove a coin from the specified c column
int AIConnectBoard::sub(int c)
{
top[c]--;
arry[c, top[c] = 0];
return 0;
}

//keeps track of where AI is currently contemplating a move
int AIConnectBoard::position()
{
int u, z, x, y, j, score;
int gh = 0, hg = 0;
score = 0;

//Empty Think
for (x = 0; x < m; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
    {
        thnk[x, y] = 0;
    }
}
for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < m; x++)
    {
        if (arry[x, y] == 0)
        {
            score += checkhole(x, y);
        }
        if (y>0)
        {
            if (thnk[x, y] == (int*)ai && arry[x, y - 1] != 0)
            {
                gh++;
            }
            if (thnk[x, y] == (int*)plyr && arry[x, y - 1] != 0)
            {
                hg++;
                score = score - 4000;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (gh > 1)
{
    score += (gh - 1) * 500;
}
if (gh == 1)
{
    score = score - 100;
}
if (hg > 1)
{
    score -= (hg - 1) * 500;
}

for (x = 0; x < m; x++)
{
    gh = 0;
    for (y = 1; y < 6; y++)
    {
        if (thnk[x, y] == (int*)ai && arry[x, y - 1] == (int*)ai)
        {
            u = 0; j = 0;
            for (int z = y - 1; 0>-1; z--)
            {
                if (thnk[x, z] == (int*)plyr)
                {
                    u = 1;
                }
                if (arry[x, z] == 0)
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (u == 0)
            {
                score -= 1500 + j*m; //m or 7?
            }
            if (u == 1)
            {
                score -= 300;
            }
        }
        if (thnk[x, y] == (int*)plyr && thnk[x, y - 1] == (int*)plyr)
        {
            u = 0; j = 0;
            for (int z = y - 1; z > -1; z--)
            {
                if (thnk[x, z] == (int*)ai)
                {
                    u = 1;
                }
                if (arry[x, z] == 0)
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (u == 0)
            {
                score -= 1500 + j*m; //m or 7?
            }
            if (u == 1)
            {
                score -= 300;
            }
        }
        if (thnk[x, y] == (int*)plyr)
        {
            u = 0;
            for (z = y - 1; y > -1; y--)
            {
                if (thnk[x, z] == (int*)ai)
                {
                    u = 1;
                }
            }
            if (u == 1)
            {
                score += 30;
            }
            if (thnk[x, y] == (int*)ai)
            {
                u = 0;
                for (z = y - 1; z > -1; z--)
                {
                    if (thnk[x, z] == (int*)plyr)
                    {
                        u = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (u == 1)
                {
                    score -= 30;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return score;
}

//check score of current hole AI is contemplating
int AIConnectBoard::checkhole(int x, int y)
{
int score = 0;
int max, min;
int d0 = 0, d1 = 0, d2 = 0, d3 = 0;

//d1  ai check rows
if ((x + 1)<m && (y - 1)>-1)
{
    if (arry[x + 1, y - 1] == (int*)ai)
    {
        d1++;
        if ((x + 2)<m && (y - 2)>-1)
        {
            if (arry[x + 2, y - 2] == (int*)ai)
            {
                d1++;
                if ((x + 3)<m && (y - 3)>-1)
                {
                    if (arry[x + 3, y - 3] == (int*)ai)
                    {
                        d1++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//d1 ai check columns
if ((x - 1) > -1 && (y + 1) < n)
{
    if (arry[x - 1, y + 1] == (int*)ai)
    {
        d1++;
        if ((x - 2) >-1 && (y + 2) < n)
        {
            if (arry[x - 2, y + 2] == (int*)ai)
            {
                d1++;
                if ((x - 3) >-1 && (y + 3) < n)
                {
                    if (arry[x - 3, y + 3] == (int*)ai)
                    {
                        d1++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d2 ai check rows
if ((x - 1)<m && (y - 1)>-1)
{
    if (arry[x - 1, y - 1] == (int*)ai)
    {
        d2++;
        if ((x - 2)<m && (y - 2)>-1)
        {
            if (arry[x - 2, y - 2] == (int*)ai)
            {
                d2++;
                if ((x - 3)<m && (y - 3)>-1)
                {
                    if (arry[x - 3, y - 3] == (int*)ai)
                    {
                        d2++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d2 ai check columns
if ((x + 1) > -1 && (y + 1) < n)
{
    if (arry[x + 1, y + 1] == (int*)ai)
    {
        d2++;
        if ((x + 2) >-1 && (y + 2) < n)
        {
            if (arry[x + 2, y + 2] == (int*)ai)
            {
                d2++;
                if ((x + 3) >-1 && (y + 3) < n)
                {
                    if (arry[x + 3, y + 3] == (int*)ai)
                    {
                        d2++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d0 ai check
if ((y - 1) > -1)
{
    if (arry[x, y - 1] == (int*)ai)
    {
        d0++;
        if ((y - 2) > -1)
        {
            if (arry[x, y - 2] == (int*)ai)
            {
                d0++;
                if ((y - 3) > -1)
                {
                    if (arry[x, y - 3] == (int*)ai)
                    {
                        d0++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d3 ai check 
if ((x - 1) > -1)
{
    if (arry[x - 1, y] == (int*)ai)
    {
        d3++;
        if ((x - 2) > -1)
        {
            if (arry[x - 2, y] == (int*)ai)
            {
                d3++;
                if ((x - 3) > -1)
                {
                    if (arry[x - 3, y] == (int*)ai)
                    {
                        d3++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d3 ai check rows
if (x + 1 < m)
{
    if (arry[x + 1, y] == (int*)ai)
    {
        d3++;
        if (x + 2 < m)
        {
            if (arry[x + 2, y] == (int*)ai)
            {
                d3++;
                if (x + 3 < m)
                {
                    if (arry[x + 3, y] == (int*)ai)
                    {
                        d3++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
max = d0;
//score manipulations
if (d1 > max){ max = d1; }
if (d2 > max){ max = d2; }
if (d3 > max){ max = d3; }
if (max == 2)
{
    score += 5;
}
if (max > 2)
{
    score += 71;
    thnk[x, y] = (int*)ai;
    if ((d1 < 3) && (d2 < 3) && (d3 < 3))
    {
        score -= 10;
    }
}
//d1 plyr check rows
if ((x + 1)<m && (y - 1)>-1)
{
    if (arry[x + 1, y - 1] == (int*)plyr)
    {
        d1++;
        if ((x + 2)<m && (y - 2)>-1)
        {
            if (arry[x + 2, y - 2] == (int*)plyr)
            {
                d1++;
                if ((x + 3)<m && (y - 3)>-1)
                {
                    if (arry[x + 3, y - 3] == (int*)plyr)
                    {
                        d1++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
}
//d1 plyr check columns
if ((x - 1) > -1 && (y + 1) < n)
{
    if (arry[x - 1, y + 1] == (int*)plyr)
    {
        d1++;
        if ((x - 2) >-1 && (y + 2) < n)
        {
            if (arry[x - 2, y + 2] == (int*)plyr)
            {
                d1++;
                if ((x - 3) >-1 && (y + 3) < n)
                {
                    if (arry[x - 3, y + 3] == (int*)plyr)
                    {
                        d1++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d2 plyr check rows
if ((x - 1)<m && (y - 1)>-1)
{
    if (arry[x - 1, y - 1] == (int*)plyr)
    {
        d2++;
        if ((x - 2)<m && (y - 2)>-1)
        {
            if (arry[x - 2, y - 2] == (int*)plyr)
            {
                d2++;
                if ((x - 3)<m && (y - 3)>-1)
                {
                    if (arry[x - 3, y - 3] == (int*)plyr)
                    {
                        d2++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d2 plyr check columns
if ((x + 1) > -1 && (y + 1) < n)
{
    if (arry[x + 1, y + 1] == (int*)plyr)
    {
        d2++;
        if ((x + 2) >-1 && (y + 2) < n)
        {
            if (arry[x + 2, y + 2] == (int*)plyr)
            {
                d2++;
                if ((x + 3) >-1 && (y + 3) < n)
                {
                    if (arry[x + 3, y + 3] == (int*)plyr)
                    {
                        d2++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d0 plyr check
if ((y - 1) > -1)
{
    if (arry[x, y - 1] == (int*)plyr)
    {
        d0++;
        if ((y - 2) > -1)
        {
            if (arry[x, y - 2] == (int*)plyr)
            {
                d0++;
                if ((y - 3) > -1)
                {
                    if (arry[x, y - 3] == (int*)plyr)
                    {
                        d0++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d3 plyr check 
if ((x - 1) > -1)
{
    if (arry[x - 1, y] == (int*)plyr)
    {
        d3++;
        if ((x - 2) > -1)
        {
            if (arry[x - 2, y] == (int*)plyr)
            {
                d3++;
                if ((x - 3) > -1)
                {
                    if (arry[x - 3, y] == (int*)plyr)
                    {
                        d3++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//d3 ai check rows
if (x + 1 < m)
{
    if (arry[x + 1, y] == (int*)plyr)
    {
        d3++;
        if (x + 2 < m)
        {
            if (arry[x + 2, y] == (int*)plyr)
            {
                d3++;
                if (x + 3 < m)
                {
                    if (arry[x + 3, y] == (int*)plyr)
                    {
                        d3++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
min = d0;
//score manipulations
if (d1 > min){ min = d1; }
if (d2 > min){ min = d2; }
if (d3 > min){ min = d3; }
if (min == 2)
{
    score -= 4;
}
if (min > 2)
{
    score -= 70;
    thnk[x, y] = (int*)plyr;
    if ((d1 < 3) && (d2 < 3) && (d3 < 3))
    {
        score += 10;
    }
}
return score;

}

//check for win condition (i.e. "conNum" in a row)
int AIConnectBoard::checkwin()
{
int r = 0;
int x, y;
for (y = 2; y > -1; y--)
{
    for (x = 0; x < m; x++)
    {
        checku(x, y, r);
    }
}
for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < conNum; x++)
    {
        check2r(x, y, r);
    }
}
for (y = 2; y>-1; y--)
{
    for (x = 0; x < conNum; x++)
    {
        checkr(x, y, r);
    }
}
for (y = 2; y>-1; y--)
{
    for (x = 3; x < m; x++)
    {
        checkl(x, y, r);
    }
}
return r;
}


//check win functions
    void AIConnectBoard::checku(int x, int y, int& r)
{
if ((arry[x, y] == (int*)2) && (arry[x, y + 1] == (int*)2) && (arry[x, y + 2] ==  (int*)2) && (arry[x, y + 3] == (int*)2))r = 2;
if ((arry[x, y] == (int*)1) && (arry[x, y + 1] == (int*)1) && (arry[x, y + 2] == (int*)1) && (arry[x, y + 3] == (int*)1))r = 1;
}

void AIConnectBoard::check2r(int x, int y, int& r)
{
if ((arry[x, y] == (int*)2) && (arry[x + 1, y] == (int*)2) && (arry[x + 2, y] == (int*)2) && (arry[x + 3, y] == (int*)2))r = 2;
if ((arry[x, y] == (int*)1) && (arry[x + 1, y] == (int*)1) && (arry[x + 2, y] == (int*)1) && (arry[x + 3, y] == (int*)1))r = 1;
}

void AIConnectBoard::checkr(int x, int y, int& r)
{
if ((arry[x, y] == (int*)2) && (arry[x + 1, y + 1] == (int*)2) && (arry[x + 2, y + 2] == (int*)2) && (arry[x + 3, y + 3] == (int*)2))r = 2;
if ((arry[x, y] == (int*)1) && (arry[x + 1, y + 1] == (int*)1) && (arry[x + 2, y + 2] == (int*)1) && (arry[x + 3, y + 3] == (int*)1))r = 1;
}

void AIConnectBoard::checkl(int x, int y, int& r)
{
if ((arry[x, y] == (int*)2) && (arry[x - 1, y + 1] == (int*)2) && (arry[x - 2, y + 2] == (int*)2) && (arry[x - 3, y + 3] == (int*)2))r = 2;
if ((arry[x, y] == (int*)1) && (arry[x - 1, y + 1] == (int*)1) && (arry[x - 2, y + 2] == (int*)1) && (arry[x - 3, y + 3] == (int*)1))r = 1;
}
```

Comment: Using `new` is asking for trouble, especially when you don't clean up any of it. Why is `b` a pointer at all? As for the 2D array, you could use a vector of vectors, but it would be better to find a matrix class to avoid the jaggedness.

Comment: This: `int** thnk = new int*[m, n];` isn't C++.. More C#. Well.. It will compile in C++ but it will not do what you think it does..

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues going on here.  Firstly:  A bit about using the "new" operator in c++:

New in c++ is not like new in Java (or other, similar languages).  It does basically the same thing, but there is no garbage collector there to clean up your mess.  Newing up local variables and then doing nothing with them (and not deleting them before the end of the function, like in your "set board" function!) causes issues called "memory leaks."

In other words, for the life of your program, there is a chunk of memory allocated for that specific piece of data that will never be given back to the allocated space your program is allotted, until you free it back up with the proper delete (or, in the case of an array, delet []), release, or free method/function, depending on the exact nature of the implementation.

So, that being said:  Initialize things by value, do it statically (as in NOT using "new"), and make sure you're using the right variables, and not declaring a new one that doesn't go anywhere.

First thing that's glaring me in the face right now is this:

```
int* top = new int[n];
```

Found in your set board function.  This is dynamically allocating a new array of integers with size "n."

The problem with doing this is that it's a local variable, and is never deleted, so the pointer to this data is lost when you leave this scope (i.e., when the function returns), meaning you can never free up that space again until your program ends (assuming the OS can handle that, which most can, but it's still not good practice to rely on it), and your actual "top" array is never truly initialized, hence the "access error."

Comment: Unfortunately it HAS to be a dynamic array as the board is not set until the user gives the dimensions. I'm going to try the std::vector fixes mentioned below and see if that starts clearing up all the new (which i only used because i couldnt figure out dynamic arrays any other way and every resource i checked showed it using the new command).

Comment: Using either vector (which I would suggest) or the array class (which allows for fixed sizes, though you could easily make your vector stop adding spaces when it's reached the user's input) would make it viable.  Yet another option would be to use a smart pointer, which behaves more or less like a regular pointer, but is more "C++ ish" than using "new" when performance isn't an issue.

[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

[Smart Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't debug your code yet. But the first thing to do is to take all the new and delete out of your code, and use `std::vector` instead. As well as simplifying your code, that would eliminate memory allocation errors as a source of the problem.

If you do that and still get a problem, then on the trouble line , change `arry[c][top[c]]` to `array.at(c).at(top[c])` and write an exception handler. If you get an exception thrown then it means you were trying to access out of bounds, which is more reliable information than a segfault.

Now, you have a lot of code like `thnk[x, y] == (int*)ai`.  `ai` is an int, so what do you think `(int *)ai` will get you?

It looks as if you have gotten a compiler warning for this line without the cast, so you guessed at some code to make the warning go away. That's a pretty bad idea in C++.  Don't use a cast ever, unless you are 100% certain what you are doing.

The warning is because `thnk[x, y]` is an `int *`, i.e. the address of an `int`. You probably meant `thnk[x][y]`.  In C, the expression `x, y` means "evaluate `x`, ignore the result, and use `y`". So it is equivalent to `thnk[y]`.

Comment: I was using the cast because i knew the array was as an int* and the cast "fixed" it (got rid of the error). Unfortunately, i was working off some c# code i did first and trying to translate it (which dynamic arrays work so much nicer in c# from what ive noticed). I did try doing [x][y] == int but was getting some problems, but ill try the vectors to see if that resolves the issue

Comment: The array isn't an `int *`, that's the whole problem.